# How to use casper-rw file for persistence

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, live-usb, persistence

I have my USB stick setup using Easy2Boot. It allows me to drop ISO files onto the USB drive and boot from there no config or tweaking needed.

I have been doing research on making it persistent. I have found that you can use a file or a partition called casper-rw.

It has info on how to use the file, but my question is. Can you have the casper-rw file directly in the root of the bootable ISO or does it need to go into a special folder on the ISO? For that matter can I even have the file in the ISO or do I need to have it directly on the USB drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ISO files cannot be mounted and then written to. [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) is a read-only file system.

So you'd need to situate a `casper-rw` file (it's a single file with a filesystem within too) in a location that's physically on the USB drive.

#### Making a writable filesystem

The Pendrive Linux website shows some details on how to go about creating a `casper-rw` filesystem. The article is titled: [Create a larger casper-rw loop file in Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-create-a-larger-casper-rw-loop-file/). **NOTE:** A `casper-rw` filesystem is just a regular filesystem that's been tucked inside a single file. In that example they're using a EXT3 filesystem within it.

#### Example

1. Make the "casper-rw" image

   ```
   $ dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=1024
   1024+0 records in
   1024+0 records out
   1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 10.958 s, 98.0 MB/s

   $ ls -l casper-rw 
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 1073741824 Apr  2 19:56 casper-rw
   ```
2. Format it as EXT3

   ```
   $ mkfs.ext3 -F casper-rw
   mke2fs 1.42.7 (21-Jan-2013)
   Discarding device blocks: done                            
   Filesystem label=
   OS type: Linux
   Block size=4096 (log=2)
   Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
   Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
   65536 inodes, 262144 blocks
   13107 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
   First data block=0
   Maximum filesystem blocks=268435456
   8 block groups
   32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
   8192 inodes per group
   Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
       32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

   Allocating group tables: done                            
   Writing inode tables: done                            
   Creating journal (8192 blocks): done
   Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
   ```
3. Mount it

   ```
   $ sudo mount -o loop casper-rw /mnt/
   ```
4. Check it out

   ```
   $ ls /mnt/
   lost+found

   $ df -h /mnt/
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/loop0      976M  1.3M  924M   1% /mnt
   ```

Comment: Ok, I know how to do that part. I already created the file system in Casper-RW. I didn't know you couldn't edit ISOs. Good to know. I have another question can you make Casper-RW an encrypted FS?

Comment: @Lofful - I don't see why not. It's just a image file with whatever filesystem you want inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Easy2Boot supports persistence for quite a few ISOs. Look in the _ISO\docs\Sample mnu files folder for examples.
You can have many ISOs all with persistence on the same USB stick.
Look on the www.easy2boot.com website and the www.rmprepusb.com website.
http://www.easy2boot.com/add-payload-files/persistence/